# Is it okay if I only ask and read, and not answer

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I usually only read questions and answers, or ask questions I have. I rarely ever answer, because most of the times, I don't feel qualified enough (read I have no idea what the question is talking about) to answer. Morally/ethically, is this okay? Or should I try to contribute by answering more?

Comment: Yes, this is okay.  Asking good Questions is an important contribution.  Content is meant to be read, and you can vote up or down as seems fitting.

Comment: Absolutely, totally, and utterly okay.

Comment: Similar older question: [Is it annoying that I don't answer questions and just ask?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6412/is-it-annoying-that-i-dont-answer-questions-and-just-ask)

Answer (score 4):

Sure, so long as your questions are good. We can't answer if you don't ask.